# Visual Studio: what is the difference between 'Build Solution' and 'Rebuild Solution' when i do not use precompiled headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, visual-studio-2022

I try to understand what is the difference between the 2 built types in visual studio (Build vs Rebuild Solution). As i know when i use precompiled headers the simple built will not complile the precompiled headers as long the code in these files remain the same, but 'rebuilt' will compile them always.
So what happend when i don't use precompiled headers?
I notice that simple built is still faster than rebuilt, what exactly does to reduce the compling time (c++)?

Comment: Rebuild is usually "Clean & Build". That is why it always compiles all C++ files since all object files are removed during "cleanup phase".

Comment: Precompiled headers are not relevant to (*incremental*) Build and Rebuild (*clean and build*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *Build* will typcally only rebuild the files that needs to be rebuilt because of changes you've made to the code.

If you create two files in your project/solution, `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`, and then *Build* the first time, both will be compiled (into `a.obj` and `b.obj`) and then linked into an `.exe` file.

If you then make changes to `a.cpp` only and select *Build* again, only `a.cpp` would be compiled (into a `a.obj`) and that `a.obj` and the already existing `b.obj` would be linked into an `.exe` file.

If you instead select *Rebuild*, `b.cpp` would also be recompiled before linking, even though you didn't make any changes to `b.cpp`.

Comment: There's now also Incremental Link-Time Code Generation (`/LCG:INCREMENTAL`) which adds an `.ipdb`  file to the mix, besides the `.obj` files. The effect is still the same; a normal build is incremental and a rebuild is a full build from scratch.